# See HTML of page after modified by Javascript

Tags: ajax, firebug

Is there any way to see the page in Firebug or other software after the content of a div has been replaced with ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can [inspect the DOM](http://getfirebug.com/dom) with FireBug which always shows the DOM at its most recent state (and of course accounts for AJAX updates):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's exactly what Firebug will show you: the current state of the DOM. Same with Chrome's developer tools.

Answer (score 2):

yes 
firebug marks the changed div in yellow and you can see the html dynamic updates in the html view